# Can I run two functions simultaneously no matter what these functions run?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

What I'd like to do is the following program to print out:

```
Running Main
Running Second
Running Main
Running Second
[...]
```

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


def main():
    while True:
        print('Running Main')
        time.sleep(1)


def second():
    while True:
        print('Running Second')
        time.sleep(1)


p1 = Process(main())
p2 = Process(second())

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

But it doesn't have the desired behavior. Instead it just prints out:

```
Running Main
Running Main
[...]
```

I suspect my program doesn't work because of the `while` statement?
Is there any way I can overcome this problem and have my program print out what I mentioned no matter what I execute in my function?

Comment: If you're on windows you need to put your code in a `main` function, otherwise the module keeps getting reimported and reexecuting all the top level code. See *"Safe importing of main module"* in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: You need to pass the functions to the `Process` instead you are *calling the function*: `p1 = Process(main())` so you need `p1 = Process(main)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems to be when you make the process vars. I suspect the reason for why the process inclusively runs the first function is because of syntax. My interpretation is that instead of creating a process out of a function you are making a process that executes a function exclusively.

When you want to create Process object you want to avoid using this

```
p1 = Process(target=main())
```

and rather write

```
p1 = Process(target=main)
```

That also means if you want to include any input for the function you will have to

```
p1 = Process(target=main, args=('hi',))
```

Comment: Combination of `if __name__ == '__main__'` and `target=main without ()` solved the problem! Thanks!